# How to serialize nested collection of objects with Jackson

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, jackson2

Having the following code:

```
public class ToSerialize {
  List<NestedObject> objs;

  public ToSerialize(List<NestedObject> objs) {
    this.objs = objs;
  }
}

public class NestedObject {
  int intValue = 0;
  String strValue = "Hello world";
}
```

How, if possible, do I setup Jackson so I get the following CSV as String output:

```
obj1.intValue,obj1.strValue,obj2.intValue,obj2.strValue,0,"Hello world",0,"Hello world"
```

I looked into writing my own custom `JsonSerializer` but can't figure it out. Still, here's my current not working serializer implementation

```
  @Override
  public void serialize(List<NestedObject> values, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
    throws IOException
  {
    int i = 1;
    for (Iterator<VsppAssetEntry> iterator = values.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
      VsppAssetEntry entry = iterator.next();
      String fieldName = "obj" + i;
      gen.writeObjectField(fieldName, entry);
      i++;
    }
```

this is throwing `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value` obviously because Jackson wrote a fieldName `objs` before entering this method.

Comment: Jackson is not really meant to use this sort of approach. There are csv processing frameworks that are designed for these, i.e. opencsv

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Jackson dataformat CSV](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv).

Consider the following CSV Schema:

```
CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder()
        .addColumn("obj")
        .addColumn("intValue")
        .addColumn("strValue")
        .build()
        .withHeader();

ToSerialize toSerialize = new ToSerialize(Arrays.asList(new NestedObject(), new NestedObject()));

String csv = new CsvMapper()
        .writerFor(ToSerialize.class)
        .with(schema)
        .writeValueAsString(toSerialize);

System.out.println(csv);
```

and the following custom Serializer…

```
public class ToSerializeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ToSerialize> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(ToSerialize toSerialize, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException {
        List<NestedObject> objs = toSerialize.getObjs();
        for (int i = 0; i < objs.size(); i++) {
            gen.writeObject("obj" + i);
            gen.writeObject(objs.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

…register it on your `ToSerialize` class…

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToSerializeSerializer.class)
public class ToSerialize {
    […]
}
```

…and it will give you…

```
obj,intValue,strValue
obj0,0,"Hello world"
obj1,0,"Hello world"
```